# Project Reactor sink unexpected behavior with backpressure buffer

Tags: java, project-reactor, backpressure

I have a multicast sink with backpressure buffer with the default size. To this sink I emit events asynchronously every 25ms from a dedicated thread. There are 3 subscribers A, B and C where B pretends to do some work through thread sleep. A and C use `subscribeOn` and B uses `publishOn` on dedicated schedulers.

I have 5 questions about the behavior of the backpressure along with the schedulers and `publishOn` vs `subscribeOn`.

1. why subscribeOn for A and C doesn't have any effect and elements are published on the emitting thread?
2. A and C stop receiving events at 257 where B is already at ~15, shouldn't A and C stop at around ~256+15=271 ?
3. after i=512 emissions start to fail on FAIL_OVERFLOW; is it because both buffers (B's publishOn 256 a sink's 256) are full? it is not true as B at this point already processed ~29 events
4. A and C start receiving events back again after B=192, why 192? also, they receive the events on the B's scheduler, why?
5. changing B's `publishOn` to `subscribeOn` pushes back the emitting thread respecting the slowest consumer (B). `subscribeOn` has again no effect, why?

Here is the runnable code. Reactor version `3.4.14`.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import reactor.core.publisher.Sinks;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import static java.util.concurrent.Executors.newScheduledThreadPool;
import static reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers.fromExecutorService;

public class SinkBackpressureBuffer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("SinkLogger");
    
    private static void sleep(long ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Sinks.Many<Integer> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();

        new Thread(() -> {
            sleep(1000);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 550; i++) { // has to be bigger than 256 + 256
                final Sinks.EmitResult emitResult = sink.tryEmitNext(i);
                if (emitResult != Sinks.EmitResult.OK) {
                    LOGGER.error("Emit for i={}, res={}", i, emitResult);
                } else {
                    LOGGER.info("Emit for i={}, res={}", i, emitResult);
                }
                sleep(25);
            }
        }).start();

        sink.asFlux()
                .subscribeOn(fromExecutorService(newScheduledThreadPool(5, new NamedThreadFactory("AAA")))) // has no effect
                .subscribe(i -> {
                    LOGGER.info("A: {}", i);
                });

        sink.asFlux()
                .publishOn(fromExecutorService(newScheduledThreadPool(5, new NamedThreadFactory("BBB"))))
                .subscribe(i -> {
                    sleep(500);
                    LOGGER.info("B: {}", i);
                });

        sink.asFlux()
                .subscribeOn(fromExecutorService(newScheduledThreadPool(5, new NamedThreadFactory("CCC")))) // has no effect
                .subscribe(i -> {
                    LOGGER.info("C: {}", i);
                });

        LOGGER.info("done");
        sleep(500000);
    }

    public static class NamedThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
        private final AtomicInteger sequence = new AtomicInteger(1);
        private final String prefix;

        public NamedThreadFactory(String prefix) {
            this.prefix = prefix;
        }

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(r);
            int seq = sequence.getAndIncrement();
            thread.setName(prefix + (seq > 1 ? "-" + seq : ""));
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            return thread;
        }
    }

}
```